# Ayuda con (const vector<int>& t : flights), en floyd algorithm

Tags: c++, array

```
//vector<vector<int>>& flights
//vector<vector<int>> vec(n, vector<int>(k + 1));
for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        vec[j][i] = vec[j][i - 1];

        for (const vector<int>& t : flights)
        {
            vec[t[1]][i] = min(vec[t[1]][i], vec[t[0]][i - 1] + t[2]);
        }
    }

}
```

Vi esta implementacion del algoritmo de floyd para los caminos mas cortos pero no entiendo que es la 't' que es creada y que es lo que contiene

Answer (score 2):

```
for (const vector<int>& t : flights)
```

El `for` que ves aquí es un elemento que se incorporó al lengueje en el estándar C++11 (que data de 2011). Es un bucle basado en rangos. Un posible equivalente *a la vieja usanza* sería:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>::const_iterator it;
for( it = flights.begin(); it != flights.end(); ++it )
{
  std::vector<int> const& t = *it;

  // ...
}
```

Como puedes ver, `t` es, en este caso, una **referencia constante** a un `vector` de tipo `int`. La referencia se usa para no hacer copias de vectores en cada iteración. Andar copiando un vector (o un conjunto de vectores) de forma intensiva en un algoritmo es una forma muy sencilla y rápida de acabar con su rendimiento.

Por otro lado, la referencia se hace constante porque el algoritmo **no debería** modificar el estado de la colección, la misma debería ser usada en modo solo lectura exclusivamente.

Answer (score 2):

> No entiendo que es la 't' que es creada.

La definición de `t` es:

```
const vector<int>& t
^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^ ^
  \     \    \    \______ Referencia
   \     \    \_______________________________________ Enteros
    \     \____________________________________ Vector
     \_____________________________ Constante
```

`t` es una referencia constante a vector de enteros. Se define dentro de un `for` de rango:

```
for (const vector<int>& t : flights)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^ ^^^^^^^
              \            \    \___ flights (que es vector<vector<int>>)
               \            \____ en
                \____ Para cada t (en forma de const vector<int>&)
```

El `for` de rango nos hace una operación para cada elemento de un contenedor, en el caso anterior dará una vuelta para cada `t` (que es referencia constante a vector de enteros) en `flights` (que es un vector de vectores de enteros).

Dado que `flights` es un vector de vectores de enteros, cada elemento de `flights` será un vector de enteros; le pedimos al bucle `for` de rango que recorra cada elemento de `flights` sin hacer copias (por eso pedimos referencia (`&`)) y sin modificar los datos (por eso pedimos que se constante (`const`)).

Podrías ahorrar unas pulsaciones si dejas que el compilador escriba el tipo de datos por ti:

```
for (const auto& t : flights)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^ ^^^^^^^
              \   \    \___ flights (que es vector<vector<int>>)
               \   \____ en
                \____ Para cada t (referencia constante a lo que toque)
```

> Y que es lo que contiene.

Cada `t` apunta (como referencia constante) a un elemento de `flights`, que al ser un vector de vectores de enteros, cada `t` será un vector de enteros.